# How to click on the Security Warning window using Selenium webdriver in IE 11?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium

[Security Warning Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtD2S.png)

This image pops up when I click on "Continue to this website (not recommended)."

Answer (score 1):

Please Try This, It works.

```
public void TestSSLerror() {

    //Download IEDriver exe and past in project
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    //Open WebSite for time being let's take http://test.com
    driver.get("https://test.com");

    //now we are going to use javascipt ,This will click on "Continue to this website (not recommended)" text and will 
    //push us to the page
    driver.navigate().to("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you can disable the security check by bypassing using required credentials, if it is not related to the test(saves time), otherwise you need to go for a third party tool like auto-it to automate it.